# Server crash - my fault or server's?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

So we have been getting a decent amount of server crashes lately and I was wondering if anyone had input as to why.

This morning I have been running some database requests through for about 30 records.  I select the records, change the values of one value in the table, and write it back to the database.

The server has just crashed now and I'm wondering if there is any way that could have to do with my code?  If 30 records can crash the server then we are in trouble when we try to access all 15,000 products...

It is also notable that we use Magento (can tend to be more robust than necessary at times)

Any thoughts?

Comment: What platform are you on? Do you mean the whole machine crashes or just some server processes? There should be logs or core files or some other diagnostics.

Comment: the problem is we outsourced the original website design and server management so I have no control over these logs or files.  All I have is the Magento error logs which don't indicate anything.  I was just wondering if 30 records could be enough to crash a site?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "crashed"?

Comment: when server crashes it's always your fault not the servers :) you missed the obvious in your question: server params, code that you are executing, errors in log files

Answer (score 0):

- when there are a lot of users trying to select 15000 lines on one server, it might cause big problems
- check your apache log (DDoS?)
- check your mysql log (maybe some unexpected loops?)